# Command to send signals to waveform in SimVision

Tags: tcl, waveform, cadence

Is there a (Tcl-)command I can use to send signals to waveform in SimVision?
Of course You can rightclick them and then select "Send to WaveForm Window", but to do that each time you start a simulation will be a pain.

In Modelsim you can easily use "add wave" in a dofile (tcl file), but strange if there would be no way to do this with ncsim...

Answer (score 3):

a minimal working example I've come up with:

```
    window new WaveWindow -name "Waveform"
    waveform using {Waveform}
    waveform add -signals tb_foo_u.module_bar_u.signal_xyz
```

You can type that in the SimVision console (if you're using irun in GUI mode). Tested in 15.20. Those are simulator-specific commands.

If you want it to be done automatically @ irun startup (using .tcl file), examine the results of running commands from the other answer, then tailor it to your needs.

For the full, verbose description of `waveform` instruction, refer to the documentation provided with the simulator under `SimVision Tcl Commands` / `waveform`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have your waveform window set up the way you like (with all desired signals), you can go to File -> Save Command Script .  This will save your window setup as a tcl file.  You can look in there to see what the tcl commands are if you are interested in doing it manually.

To restore the waveform window next time, simply go to File -> Source Command Script and select the file you had saved previously.
Note: I'm using SimVision 12.10